# Batch file to rename a file to include the Wednesday's date of the current week followed by a string of text

Tags: batch-file, command-prompt

I am trying to create a batch file that can rename a .pdf file to include the Wednesday's date of the current week followed by a string of text. The current example template for the filename should be "YYYY-M-D Document-03.pdf". So an example filename should be renamed to "**2023-6-14 Document-03.pdf**".

Below are the code I am working with:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "dayOfWeek=Wednesday"
for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /t') do (
    set "day=%%a"
    set "month=%%b"
    set "year=%%c"
)

for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=: " %%a in ('time /t') do (
    set "hour=%%a"
    set "minute=%%b"
    set "second=%%c"
)

set "dateString=%year%-%month%-%day%"
set "newFileName=%dateString% SRP-B332-4.4.1.ab.pdf"

ren *.pdf "%newFileName%"

echo Done!
```

The code currently incorrectly renames the filename as:

```
14-06-Wed Document-03.pdf
```

Help on this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this, using PowerShell as a helper, get you what you need for your `%dateString%`?

```bash
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions
Set "dateString="
For /F %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
 -NoProfile -Command "$Today=(Get-Date).Date;"^
 "$Today.AddDays([Int][DayOfWeek]::WednesDay-$Today.DayOfWeek).ToString('yyyy-M-d')"
 2^>NUL') Do Set "DateString=%%G"
If Not Defined dateString GoTo :EOF
Rem Your code using the resulting variable named dateString goes below.
Echo %dateString%
Pause
```

Answer (score 0):

Powershell can sometimes be slow to start when invoked on my PCs so often a cmd approach is much faster.

This calling a batch file is slower than most I run (since calling system with javascript) but for me it is faster than PowerShell.

SetWed.cmd

```
@echo off
call jTimestamp  -C "OUD=-3,OD=wed:0" /F "{yyyy}-{mm}-{dd}" -r string
echo ren "%~f1" "%string% %~nx1"
```

Once tested for that offset (OUD is go back -3 days for nearest Wednesday on Thu,Fri,Sat of current week days, otherwise it will hunt for next Wednesday) then remove the last  line "echo"

DBenhams jtimestamp v2.1 can be downloaded or copied from https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=7523

Usage drag and drop a single file or run in folder with set of files

For example from command line (use %% as double in a batch file)

`for %f in (?????.pdf) do @setWed %f`

```
ren "C:\Users\my\Downloads\Apps\data.pdf" "2023-06-14 data.pdf"
ren "C:\Users\my\Downloads\Apps\data1.pdf" "2023-06-14 data1.pdf"
ren "C:\Users\my\Downloads\Apps\mypdf.pdf" "2023-06-14 mypdf.pdf"
ren "C:\Users\my\Downloads\Apps\print.pdf" "2023-06-14 print.pdf"
```

result

```
>dir 2023*.*
 Volume in drive C is OS
 Directory of C:\Users\my\Downloads\Apps

2023-06-14  03:12            28,330 2023-06-14 data.pdf
2023-06-14  03:50            83,823 2023-06-14 data1.pdf
2023-06-11  20:10            70,326 2023-06-14 mypdf.pdf
2023-06-11  20:16            70,385 2023-06-14 print.pdf
               4 File(s)        252,864 bytes
```

Comment: powershell can be slow to start from cmd, but if writing the script from scratch in powershell then it'll be significantly better and faster. And powershell startup can also be made faster by turning things like sourcing profile off